# Is v-show not working on static elements?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am not a web developer and this is the first time I play with a web framework - so please go easy on me. The framework I'm trying to learn is vue.js. Version 3.

What I try to achieve:

- 4 app instances. (nav, defaultApp, bootstrapApp, vueApp).
- Depending on the navbar item I select, one of the 3 other apps should show. The others shall hide.

I looked at various places on the internet about how to do it and added console.log() output, which convinces me, that the calls actually happen as I think they should.

I am aware, that there are alternatives, but the `v-show` approach seems most readable to me.

What is not working:

- The 3 apps are visible all the time and never get hidden.

It is probably a very silly mistake on my part. Who can spot it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning web framworks</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" 
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" 
          crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <!-- TODO: Make sure to use the production build (*.prod.js) when deploying for production.<!-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a @click.prevent="showDefault" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a @click.prevent="showBootstrap" class="nav-link" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a @click.prevent="showVue" class="nav-link" href="#">Vue.js</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div v-show="isShow" id="default-content">
      <p>default content</p>
    </div>
    <div v-show="isShow" id="bootstrap-content">
      <p>bootstrap content</p>
    </div>
    <div v-show="isShow"
          id="vue-content">
      <p>vue content</p>
    </div>

    <script 
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue

      let defaultApp = createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            isShow: true,
          }
        },
        watch: {
          isShow(val,oldVal) {
            console.log(`defaultApp.isShow( ${oldVal} -> ${val} )`);
          }
        }
      }).mount("#default-content");
      let bootstrapApp = createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            isShow: false,
          }
        },
        watch: {
          isShow(val,oldVal) {
            console.log(`bootstrapApp.isShow( ${oldVal} -> ${val} )`);
          }
        }
      }).mount("#bootstrap-content");
      let vueApp = createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            isShow: false,
          }
        },
        watch: {
          isShow(val,oldVal) {
            console.log(`vueApp.isShow( ${oldVal} -> ${val} )`);
          }
        }
      }).mount("#vue-content");

      let nav = createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            // pages: [
            //   { title: "Navbar", url: "#default-content" },
            //   { title: "Bootstrap", url: "#bootstrap-content" },
            //   { title: "Vue.js", url: "#vue-content" },
            // ],
          };
        },
        methods: {
          showDefault: function() {
            console.log("showDefault()");
            defaultApp.$data.isShow = true;
            bootstrapApp.$data.isShow = false;
            vueApp.$data.isShow = false;
          },
          showBootstrap: function() {
            console.log("showBootstrap()");
            defaultApp.$data.isShow = false;
            bootstrapApp.$data.isShow = true;
            vueApp.$data.isShow = false;
          },
          showVue: function () {
            console.log("showVue()");
            defaultApp.$data.isShow = false;
            bootstrapApp.$data.isShow = false;
            vueApp.$data.isShow = true;
          }

        }
      }).mount('#navbar');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use `v-show` on the App "root" elements

Comment: @JaromandaX So I surround the apps divs with another div block?

Comment: nope, you surround each of the three apps content with a div

Comment: @Did that and it works. No one mentioned that it would not work on root elements - thanks! Now I am a 1% web developer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use v-show on the root element of the apps - probably treat the root element as not being part of the "vue" App at all, it's just a container for the App

Instead, use it on the content

In your example, just the `<p>` but you may want to wrap actual content in a div or appropriate

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

let defaultApp = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            isShow: true,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        isShow(val, oldVal) {
            console.log(`defaultApp.isShow( ${oldVal} -> ${val} )`);
        },
    },
}).mount("#default-content");
let bootstrapApp = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            isShow: false,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        isShow(val, oldVal) {
            console.log(`bootstrapApp.isShow( ${oldVal} -> ${val} )`);
        },
    },
}).mount("#bootstrap-content");
let vueApp = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            isShow: false,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        isShow(val, oldVal) {
            console.log(`vueApp.isShow( ${oldVal} -> ${val} )`);
        },
    },
}).mount("#vue-content");

let nav = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
        };
    },
    methods: {
        showDefault: function () {
            console.log("showDefault()");
            defaultApp.$data.isShow = true;
            bootstrapApp.$data.isShow = false;
            vueApp.$data.isShow = false;
        },
        showBootstrap: function () {
            console.log("showBootstrap()");
            defaultApp.$data.isShow = false;
            bootstrapApp.$data.isShow = true;
            vueApp.$data.isShow = false;
        },
        showVue: function () {
            console.log("showVue()");
            defaultApp.$data.isShow = false;
            bootstrapApp.$data.isShow = false;
            vueApp.$data.isShow = true;
        },
    },
}).mount("#navbar");
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a @click.prevent="showDefault" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a @click.prevent="showBootstrap" class="nav-link" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a @click.prevent="showVue" class="nav-link" href="#">Vue.js</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="default-content">
  <p v-show="isShow">default content</p>
</div>
<div id="bootstrap-content">
  <p v-show="isShow">bootstrap content</p>
</div>
<div id="vue-content">
  <p v-show="isShow">vue content</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using multiple apps?
You can easily solve this by using one app and storing the visibility states of those pages in there.

Comment: Yes, there will be code outside view apps, which fetches data and feeds it into the app. So I wanted to see how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the same "isShow" data property for all three instances (defaultApp, bootstrapApp, and vueApp). This means that when you update "isShow" in one app instance, it affects all three, which is why all content sections are always visible.

Comment: Nope - three instances with their own "state". The state property has the same name but it is not the same property as they reside in different app instances.